# Traverse through each row for a column text

Tags: loops, protractor

I have a below [grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UY5os.png)

The html code is at [pastebin.com/GBP3AZNQ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UY5os.png)

I want to verify whether "test123" is present. I want to traverse through each row of column master obligationname and look for the text test123.

Can anyone guide me how to do this?

Comment: Post any relevant code in you question and see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: hi Fcin, i have added the code here since it is big -  pastebin.com/GBP3AZNQ..that is what mentioned in the original post..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the `parent class` and achieve this as follows:

```
element.all(by.xpath("//div[@class='ui-grid-cell-contents ng-scope ng-binding']")).getText().then(function (msg) 
{ 
console.log("Grid contains" + msg);
expect(msg).toContain("test123");
}
```

If suppose the Master_obligation name is `test_876`
Then

```
var master_obligation_name= "test_876" ;
```

Suppose you are filling obligation_name as:

```
element(by.xpath("path to master_obligation text field")).sendKeys(master_obligation_name);
```

After creation of the row, validating the newly added row:

```
 var row_check = element(by.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'test_876')]"));
 if(row_check.isPresent())
 {
  row_check.getText().then(function (msg) {  
        console.log("Grid contains" + msg);
  });
 }
```

Happy Learning. :-)

Comment: hey @kishan, but the output is always failing even the value is present. even though there is a entry with test_r1, it is failing. - refer screenshot - http://prnt.sc/eru6bk

Comment: `element.all(by.xpath("//div[@class='ui-grid-cell-contents ng-scope ng-binding']")).get(13).getText().then(function (msg) 
{ 
console.log("Grid contains" + msg);
expect(msg).toContain("test123");
} `

Comment: What you can do is, take a count of number of rows which are already there let us say as `x` and stored it in a variable. Then you put `get(x+1)` so it will go to new entry only and try to validate new entry instead of `get(13)`.

Comment: I don't know why are you making it so complicated. Your test case should check whether the new entered row is successfully saved or not.

Comment: You can simply achieve it as : `Just check the  newly entered Master Obligation name` and validate it through a `expect`

Comment: hmm right..thats how you told me to before..but we thought going through a loop traverse is a good way...you think old method is better?

Comment: Yes. Our scenario Should check that the new row is added successfully. to keep it simpler and easy to understand.

Comment: Then you traverse for newly added row only

Comment: Please provide me the latest html code of the grid. let's finish this

Comment: hallo @kishan, good morning. this is the latest code - prnt.sc/eru6bk  the requirement is to verify test123 against each column of master obligation name and break the loop and once the test123 is found and say entry is present

Comment: This link `prnt.sc/eru6bk` is showing me screenshot of error on console

Comment: Send me html code as a file not a screenshot please.

Comment: sorry @kishan...latest code is here - pastebin.com/NNSVuikS

Comment: See my answer now. This is it . enjoy

Comment: thanks a ton..this is working...if the element is present, test_123 is present and it not available, it is failing.

Comment: i have passed like this                                                             var testvar = "'test_protractor_1'";
var row_check = element(by.xpath("//div[contains(text(),"+testvar+")]"));
 row_check.getText().then(function (msg) {
 if (row_check.isPresent()) {
  console.log("Grid contains========== " + msg);
  }
else {
 console.log("Grid not contains ======= " + msg);
 }
if the value is present, it goes to the loop and print but in case if the value is not present, it says "no element found using element(by.xpath(....) and not going to else loop.

Comment: Just put `else` loop and say
else {console.log("no element found")}

Comment: yes i have tried like that but it is not going inside only if the text is not present.so, it is throwing error saying no element found by xpath...

Comment: I can't debug what you have written bro. Just try at your end. `if else` should work.

Comment: ok sure...i am also thinking it should be working...will check once again...thanks for your time

Comment: i know this is too much to bug you..but reply only if you have time...if i want to put this page object way, i should keep the element (by.xpath) in one file and the verification in helper file right? or you have any good suggestion

Comment: yesterday the code was working but i had run again and it is giving me module details instead of the column details. :( :(

Comment: it is suddenly saying more than one element found for  element(by.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'test_protractor')]"));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139936/discussion-between-kishan-patel-and-kavitha).

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement can be fulfilled by using element.all().each() method of Protractor API. Please follow below code. Put the locator which gives all rows of a particular column in the below code.It will work perfectly.

```
element.all(by.css('locatorwhichgiveallrows')).each(function(rowElement,  
            index) {
          rowElement.getText().then(function (rowText) {
          if(rowText=="test123"){
              return true;}
     });
}).then(function(isPresent){
console.log("test123 is Present"+isPresent);
});
```

Comment: this one is working. it is verifying against each column. but the output is little different. it is comparing the test123 against each column and throwing error. instead i want in such a way that , it should compare and pass the test once the test123 is reached. how to do that?

Comment: @kav do you want to check each column of a row and pass if test123 is present?

Comment: you are right...the requirement is to verify test123 against each column of master obligation name and break the loop and once the test123 is found and say entry is present

Comment: thanks for the reply. but this is not working as expected.eventhough the value test123 is not present, the output is test123 is presentnull

Answer (score 0):

check this code out. it check if the given text is available in the table.

```
    this.searchCourseGrid = function(course){
          var row = element.all(by.css('css path to tr'));
          var cells = row.all(by.tagName('td'));
          var cellTexts = cells.map(function (cell) {
          return cell.getText();
          }).then(function(cellTexts){
            expect(cellTexts).toContain(course);
          });
};
```

Comment: @Acid..thankyou ! i will give a try and let you know

Comment: in the grid i dont have tr or td. so, i have  tried as below:                         var cells = element.all(by.xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'uiGrid-0008-cell')]/div")) ------this will identify all the cells of master obligation name column
                    var cellTexts = cells.map(function (cell) {
                        return cell.getText();
                    }).then(function (cellTexts) {
                        expect(cellTexts).toContain("test_r");
                    });       it is failing because it is comparing with all the entries of that column. instead should check 1 by 1

Comment: try to replace map with a filter function.

Comment: if i change the map to filter, it is throwing very weird error messages

Comment: can u share the html?