# how to put verification in pageobject model in protractor

Tags: protractor

I have a code (credit to @kishanpatel) [Traverse-through-each-row-for-a-column-text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179543/traverse-through-each-row-for-a-column-text) which will verify whether the value is added in grid or not. i want to put this in my page object. i was thinking to add the elements into page object and the if condition in a different helper file similar to selenium but i am not sure is that the right appraoch. see the details below.

if I call the mo.helper in spec.ts, it says `gridcheck.ispresent()` is not a function. How to handle this scenario?

**code:**

```
it('verify the grid that master obligation is added', function () {
        var testvar = "'test_protractor'";
        var row_check = element(by.xpath("//div[contains(text()," + testvar + ")]"));
        if (row_check.isPresent()) {
            row_check.getText().then(function (msg) {
                if (row_check.isPresent()) {
                    console.log("Grid contains========== " + msg);
               }
         });
      }
  });
```

i have the below method in mo.ts(page object page):

```
 this.grid = function (value) {
        // var testvar = "'test_protractor'";
        var row_check = element(by.xpath("//div[contains(text()," + value + ")]"));
        return require('./mohelper.ts')
    }
}
```

**mohelper.ts:**

```
require('../page/mo.ts')
var mohelper = function () {

    this.gridvaluepresent = function () {
        require('../page/mo.ts')
        var gridcheck = mo.grid();
        if(gridcheck.isPresent()) {
            gridcheck.getText().then(function (msg) {
                if (gridcheck.isPresent()) {
                    console.log("Grid contains========== " + msg);
                }
            })
        }
   }
}

module.exports = new mohelper();
```

**spec.ts:**

```
it('go to corresponding module and verify whether the master obligation is added ', function () {
        browser.sleep(10000);
        taxhome.selectmodule;
        taxhome.selectmoduledropdown(1);
        mo.grid("test_protractor");
        mohelper.gridvaluepresent();
 });
```

Comment: It is messy. Show me `taxhome.selectmodule;
        taxhome.selectmoduledropdown(1);` helper files . Also ` var row_check = element(by.xpath("//div[contains(text()," + value + ")]"));
        return require('./mohelper.ts')` should be ` var row_check = element(by.xpath("//div[contains(text()," + value + ")]"));
        return row_check  `

Comment: tax.selectmodule is another step to make sure the module is loaded....the code as below. i have attached the helper file in the question.please refer mohelper.ts.  this.module = function () {

        var elem = element(by.linkText('FATCA(201) - 07'))
        var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(elem));
    }

    this.selectmodule = function () {

        element(by.id('s2id_TaxProcessMod')).click();
       
    }

Comment: if i update as return row_check, it is returning the rowentries and not validating as i mentioned in the helper file; even the value i passed in conf.ts is not passed to the mo.grid function. i have passed "test_protractor" but in the output it is verified against  undefined

Comment: thanks @Sudharsan Selvaraj for the edit

Comment: Why 2 files i.e. `mo.ts` and `mohelper.ts` ? can't you keep them in one file as those are of 1 page only. M I right?

Comment: another team mate who working on selenium has a framework which has condition kept in separate helper file.so i thought it will be a good approach...but what do you suggest?

Comment: There should be a single helper file for each page.

Comment: so, instead of keeping in separate file, i should keep in mo.ts itself right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things here to be considered -

1) Most of the protractor's api methods are asynchronous i.e. they return promises you have to resolve/reject them to perform actions.

`isPresent()` also returns a promise, you need to resolve it-

```
var row_check = element(by.xpath("//div[contains(text()," + value + ")]"));
row_check.isPresent().then(function(present) {
    if(present) { // it returns a boolean value
    row_check.getText().then(function (msg) {
    console.log("Grid contains========== " + msg);
});
}
});
```

2) Since you are using TypeScript , use its syntax rather than conventional js-

```
let row_check = element(by.xpath("//div[contains(text()," + value + ")]")); // Block scoped variable using 'let'
row_check.isPresent().then((present) => {   // notice the thick arrow
    if(present) {
    row_check.getText().then((msg) => {
    console.log("Grid contains========== " + msg);
});
}
});
```

3) Maintain Page Objects efficiently and readable-

All the helper methods, elements etc. for a single page should go in a single page object. Write them in separate classes, typescript uses the concept of classes and transpiles them to global functions.

**moHelper.ts**

```
import {ElementFinder, element} from 'protractor';

export class MoHelper {

  public row_check: ElementFinder; // its of element finder type

  gridValueCheck(value : string) {
    row_check = element(by.xpath("//div[contains(text()," + value + ")]")); // please use Css selectors instead of Xpath!    
    row_check.isPresent().then((present) => {
    if(present) {
    row_check.getText().then((msg) => {
      return msg; // here you are returning the msg of the row from your page!
      });
     }
   });
  }      

  }
```

Your **spec.ts** should validate that row msg!

```
import {MoHelper} from './moHelper.ts'
let mo: MoHelper = new MoHelper();

it('go to corresponding module and verify whether the master obligation is added ', () => {
    browser.sleep(10000); // please refrain from using sleeps instead use Expected Conditions
    taxhome.selectmodule;
    taxhome.selectmoduledropdown(1);
    expect(mo.gridValueCheck("test_protractor")).toEqual("Your Expected Message");

 });
```

Please find the links for your reference to understand the above in more detail-

- [isPresent](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.isPresent)
- [Getting started with typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)
- [Using page objects in protractor/style guide](http://www.protractortest.org/#/style-guide)
- [Expected Conditions](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions)

Comment: Thanks @ram this is really helpful...i have to learn a lot :)

Comment: Depending on the version of Typescript you are using you can also use the `async / await`. This means that "don't" need to resolve for example `row_check.isPresent()` with a `then`, but can say `if (await row_check.isPresent())`. The await will stop the "execution" and waits until it is resolved. It will make the code more readable. See also [this](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/async-and-await-in-typescript) for a simple example